# Copy binary tree in order

Tags: c++, tree

The code I wrote so far is:

```
void copyInOrder(TNode *orgTree, Tnode *& copyTree){
    if(orgTree !=NULL){
        copyInOrder(orgTree->left_link);
        //create leftmost node of tree but how to link to parent
        copyInOrder(orgTree->right_link);
    }
}
```

I dont know how to link to the parent to the nodes as its inorder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it would be something like this.

```
void copyInOrder(TNode *orgTree, Tnode *& copyTree){
    if(orgTree !=NULL){
        //left side
        TNode newLeftNode = cloneNode(orgTree->left_link);
        copyTree->left_link = newLeftNode;
        copyInOrder(orgTree->left_link, copyTree->left_link);

        //right side
        TNode newRightNode = cloneNode(orgTree->right_link);
        copyTree->right_link = newRightNode;
        copyInOrder(orgTree->right_link, copyTree->right_link);
    }
}
```

Comment: where is the definition of cloneNode?

Comment: @user432495 I didn't write it, but it would be a method that created a new node based on the data from another one.

Answer (score 5):

Suppose `orgTree` points to  root (`2`). For copying, we have to do the following:

[image]

1. create a node at `copyTree`, and the copy the value 2 into it
2. if `orgTree->left != NULL`, call `copyInOrder( orgTree->left, copyTree->left );`
3. if `orgTree->right != NULL`, call `copyInOrder( orgTree->right, copyTree->right );`

BTW, this type of traversal is known as [pre-order traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Pre-order,_NLR), in-order traversal is different.

Answer (score 3):

```
tnode *copy(tnode *root) {
     tnode *new_root;
     if(root!=NULL){
         new_root=new tnode;
         new_root->data=root->data;
         new_root->lchild=copy(root->lchild);
         new_root->rchild=copy(root->rchild);
     } else return NULL;
     return new_root;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a recursive method that works and is simple

```
Tnode* CopyInOrder(Tnode* root){
    if(root == NULL){return NULL;}
    else{
        Tnode* temp = new Tnode;
        temp -> data = root -> data;
        temp -> left = copyInOrder(root -> left);
        temp -> right = copyInOrder(root -> right);
        return temp;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not authorized to flag or comment. Maybe someone who is authorized will take action on the hijacked link. And then, maybe delete my post (this post) since it will no longer be relevant.

Referring to the post of Oct 12 '10 at 21:02 by Arun:

I inspected the link (i.e., right-click, then click on "inspect"). The URL looks legitimate. However, when I actually click on the link, I get redirected to a completely different URL of a website that wants to download and install a plugin. Norton Security blocks the website. To me, it looks like the original link was hijacked.

The original post shows knowledge and helpfulness.

For safety, maybe we should change to google the search term "pre-order traversal."